# RadMenu hide submenu

Tags: telerik, radmenu

I am using a Radmenu. I like to hide a Submenu item.

The menu looks like following. Note that Car is the main Menu and Dodge, Toyota and Honda are submenus.

Cars
 - Dodge
 - Toyota
 - Honda

I am trying to do something like the following but won't work:

```
     protected void RadMenu1_ItemCreated(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenuEventArgs e)
     {
      if (e.Item is RadMenuItem)
       {

        if (e.Item.Parent != null && e.Item.Parent is RadMenuItem)
        {
            if (e.Item.Menu.FindItemByText("Honda"))
            {
                e.Item.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you hide the item in Page_Load if the menu is defined declaratively in the html or after calling the DataBind() method, if the menu is databound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet and let me know if any concern.

**ASPX**

```
<div>
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadMenu ID="RadMenu1" runat="server"  OnPreRender="RadMenu1_PreRender">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="cars">
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Honda"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Toyota"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
        </Items>
    </telerik:RadMenu>
</div>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void RadMenu1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RadMenuItem item in (sender as RadMenu).Items)
    {
        if (item.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (RadMenuItem citem in item.Items)
            {   
                if (citem.Text != "Honda")
                {
                    citem.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Hide top menu cars
protected void RadMenu1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (RadMenuItem item in (sender as RadMenu).Items)
{
    if (item.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        if(item.Text == "cars")
        {
          item.Visible = false;
        }
        foreach (RadMenuItem citem in item.Items)
        {   
            if (citem.Text != "Honda")
            {
                citem.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Jayesh, can you assist me on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216099/radgrid-on-edit-change-label-of-text-box

Comment: Hi Jayesh, what is the best way to hide the top menu "cars".  I have some top level menus in my code I need to hide.

Comment: if only one item in top menu then I would suggest that please set 'RadMenu1.Visible="false"' because empty menu also created some 'div' element in page and if you have more then one menu on top level then you can only hide that option and I will also update my above post soon.

Answer (score 0):

Eight years old, but I have a slightly different solution, based on the solution @Jayesh provided. Nothing in the ASPX page at all, since the event is handled in Page_Load.

**ASPX.CS:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        return;
    }
    Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenu topLevel = RadMenu1;
    foreach(RadMenuItem item in topLevel.Items)
    {
        LookForRadMenuItems(item);
    }
}

private void LookForRadMenuItems(RadMenuItem sender)
{
    if(sender.Text == "Honda")
    {
        sender.Visible = false;
    }
    foreach(RadMenuItem item in sender.items)
    {
        LookForRadMenuItems(item);
    }
}
```

This will look for all instances of "Honda" in all menus and submenus, and hide them. You can make it more flexible, by checking if the text `.contains` "Honda" instead, for instance, or creating a dictionary or hashtable for looking for more than one item at a time.

My particular application is actually in VB.NET, so here is the code equivalent for that:

**VB.NET**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    If Page.IsPostBack Then Exit Sub
    Dim topLevel As Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenu = RadMenu1
    For Each item As RadMenuItem In topLevel.Items
        LookForRadMenuItems(item)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub LookForRadMenuItems(sender as RadMenuItem)
    If sender.Text = "Honda" Then
        sender.Visible = false
    End If
    For Each(item As RadMenuItem In sender.Items)
        LookForRadMenuItems(item)
    Next
End Sub
```