# RadGrid on Edit Change label of Text Box

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I like to change the label of the text box on Edit. I am having a problem
in that I need to click on the edit feature twice for that to happen:

```
     <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="rdReport" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" Skin="Metro"  OnItemCommand="ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rdReport_ItemDataBound" OnPreRender="rdReport_PreRender" DataSourceID="FountainSource" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" AllowAutomaticDeletes="true">
                        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID" CommandItemDisplay="None">
                            <Columns>
                                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />                                   
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LocName" HeaderText="Location" ReadOnly="true" /> 
                                <     
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Field1Value" HeaderText="Custom Field1" />
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Field2Value" HeaderText="Custom Field2" />
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Field3Value" HeaderText="Custom Field3" />

                                <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                                    ConfirmTitle="Delete" ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" />
                            </Columns>
                            <EditFormSettings>
                                <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
                            </EditFormSettings>
                        </MasterTableView>
                        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
                    </telerik:RadGrid>

 protected void rdReport_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)   
 {

  // Edit Mode
  if ((e.Item is GridEditFormItem) && (e.Item.IsInEditMode))   
  {  
        rdReport.MasterTableView.GetColumn("Field1").HeaderText =  "MyCustomFieldName";
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data = new[] {
        new { ID = 1, Name ="Name1"},
        new { ID = 2, Name ="Name2"}
    };
    RadGrid1.DataSource = data;
}

protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditableItem item = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
        TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)item["Name"].Controls[0];
        (txtBox.Parent.Parent.Controls[0] as TableCell).Text = (txtBox.Parent.Parent.Controls[0] as TableCell).Text.Replace("Name:", "yourtext:");
    }
}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Hi Jayesh. Still not working. Just when I edit I like to change the field name of Field1Value to something else.

Comment: Could you please create new page and try with above code and let me know its working or not? if its not working than let me know else please provide your full code so I will try to resolve this issue in your code.

Comment: Might you have an email address that I can send to

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I SEE WHAT I DID. ISSUE FIXED

Comment: Thanks, My apologies - for security purpose I had removed my last comments which had my email address.

Comment: Yes, no problem. I have another question pertaining to hiding a field on edit at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245141/radgrid-make-field-invisible-on-edit