# RadGrid make field invisible on Edit

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="rdReport" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" Skin="Metro"  OnItemCommand="ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rdReport_ItemDataBound" OnPreRender="rdReport_PreRender" DataSourceID="FountainSource" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" AllowAutomaticDeletes="true">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID" CommandItemDisplay="None">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />                                   
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LocName" HeaderText="Location" ReadOnly="true" /> 
            <     
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Field1Value" HeaderText="Custom Field1" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Field2Value" HeaderText="Custom Field2" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Field3Value" HeaderText="Custom Field3" />

            <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                ConfirmTitle="Delete" ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" />
        </Columns>
        <EditFormSettings>
            <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
        </EditFormSettings>
    </MasterTableView>
    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

On Edit, I like to make a field invisible.
I am using the following code which works but want to check to see if it is best practice:

```
protected void rdReport_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Edit Mode
    if ((e.Item is GridEditFormItem) && (e.Item.IsInEditMode))
    {
        GridEditFormItem fndColumn = (GridEditFormItem)e.Item;
        fnColumn["Field1Value"].Parent.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which was provided by you is perfect but it would be nice if you will also add UniqueName property in each column. If we will not assign the UniqueName than it is consider DataField value as UniqueName.

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn DataField="Field1Value" HeaderText="Custom Field1" UniqueName="Field1Value" />
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void rdReport_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Edit Mode
    if ((e.Item is GridEditFormItem) && (e.Item.IsInEditMode))
    {
        GridEditFormItem fndColumn = (GridEditFormItem)e.Item;
        fnColumn["Field1Value"].Parent.Visible = false; // "Field1Value" is column uniquename
    }
}
```

Let me know if you required more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggested alternative. I've worked with telerik a few times, and it is a pain to say the least. What you could do is also add a tertiary condition to the parent container. If in edit mode, then show a class, such as 'edit', or 'current'. If not in edit mode, don't show the class. Then, in your CSS you can select for whatever element you want to hide.

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="whateverisgenerated" class="uniqueclass" />
</div>
```

Then, when in edit mode, you will have

```
<div class="edit">
<input type="text" id="whateverisgenerated" class="uniqueclass" />
</div>
```

With your CSS:

```
div.edit input.uniqueclass { display: none; }
```

As for your telerik control (I just grabbed something from your code), you can do the following to add your class:

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" ConfirmTitle="Delete" ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" CssClass="uniqueclass" />
```

I added `CssClass="uniqueclass"` in the control above.

What I provided is just an example. I hope you find a use for it. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to use server side visible property in place of client side display property. It may be possible that some user might be change its display property in browser (using developer tool) and update/see its value.

Comment: I'm a UI developer, not server-side :) But yes, I think a server-side code solution is better. I just wanted to pass an alternative along. Thanks Jayesh.